# Plotly Graph Objects adding horizontal line aka add_hline not working

Tags: plotly

[image]

I am trying to add horizontal line in my chart.
Where I tried using add_hline

```
var layout = {
    dragmode: 'pan',
    autosize: true,
    showlegend: show_legend,
    add_hline:{y:280} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try shapes

```
shapes:  [
    {
    type: 'line',
    x0: 0,
    y0: 280,
    x1: 0,
    y1: 280,
    
  }
```